# Add an additional page to an Angular SPA

Tags: angularjs

**The Scenario**

- I'm developing the front-end (CSS only) of an Angular SPA.
- I'm not especially familiar with Angular routing.
- I'd like to add a standalone page containing Bootstrap components *just* for development purposes (yes, I know this means it won't be a *single* page application anymore). This way I have one unified view with all the components so I don't have to switch back and forth while working on the CSS. It also acts as documentation for the Bootstrap for the other devs to refer to.

**What I've tried**

I originally added a `bootstrap.html` page to the app folder, alongside the app's `index.html` This worked at first, but has now stopped working. **What would be the best/standard way to achieve something like this?**

**Update:** I've managed to fix some of the JS errors, so the page is up and running again. My question remains though: **"is there a way of adding a standalone page that is considered standard/best practise, or is it literally just add a separate HTML page at the app root?"**

Comment: What do you meant by stopped working? Any error on console? It's just a static page with stylings  &amp;amp; some js functions of bootstrap.js right? It should work from one of route, within SPA

Comment: Can you confirm which Angular version you're using? (You've tagged angularjs, but sounds like you mean Angular (version 2+).
If you're using Angular 2+, are you building a CLI based project?

Comment: @Shantanu It's no longer routing to the bootstrap page; there are a bunch of errors in the console, but as I'm not developing the backend nor familiar with Angular, I can't figure out which errors are pertinent. My question is more 'is this the best way fo doing this, or am I chasing my tail?'

Comment: @Steveland83 It's Angular v1.5.8. It's all web-based.

Comment: @Dre The best option is having route for your static HTML. It&#39;s actually pretty simple. you don&#39;t even need controller for that view just the template &amp; you can have plaine js/jQuery code added to your index.html through script tag for any modal, etc which requires JavaScript. In $routeProvider you've to create just one entry with unique routepath

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `target='_self'` in your linking anchor tag, this should force a full page reload, and that will avoid the angular routing - which is where I expect your request is getting hijacked (by design).

e.g.

```
<a href="http://my-app.com/bootstrap.html" target="_self">link</a>
```

*Answering your updated question*
Not to my knowledge, since (as you correctly pointed out) this mixes the SPA design pattern.